# What language is most similar to JavaScript?

Tags: programming-languages

I am looking for a language that

1. has First class functions
2. is dynamic
3. has prototypical inheritance
4. does not have too many features (i.e is easy to get into and write first program).

I have been programming in JavaScript for quite some time and have gotten quite fond of it. Are there any other languages that have similar design?

Edit (just some clarification)

I know a bit of c#.After doing some programming in node js I really started to appreciate javascript and ease of its use.However outside of web development javascript falls short.Sure there are libraries like [app.js](http://appjs.org/) that allows desktop programming but that's about it.Which is why I was looking for a more general purpose sripting language that has the above mentioned features.I listed those features to make the question more in tune with stack exchange policies other wise it would probably have been closed.

Comment: Not sure if this question is on topic here, and personaly I would choose a language preferablyon the kind of project I want to implement. That said maybe [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) would fit your description best.

Comment: Also: Please don't write "Java-Script". [Java and JavaScript are as similar as car and carpet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/40342).

Comment: is ActionScript cheating?

Comment: Also: try to learn a language that is **not** similar to one you already know. This way you'll learn more!

Comment: Comparison of JS to other languages: http://hammerprinciple.com/therighttool/items/javascript

Comment: Nice @iCanLearn you should add it as an answer

Comment: @Akshat: Thanks, but it's just a link and I don't think it's answer worthy unless I make a summary of it or add something to it. I don't really have time to do that right now, but you (or anybody else) can do it if you want to.

Comment: My dear friend: I think javascript is the best choice as a general purpose language, nodejs + nwjs for desktop, phonegap and soon jxcore for mobilephones, it has reached microcontrollers too (espurino). Now days, everything that can be programed can be programed with javascript. A javascript lover.. (sorry about my english)

Comment: You might consider [asmjs](http://asmjs.org/) which is designed to be *generated*. Look also into languages like [HOP](http://hop.inria.fr) which are *generating* Javascript.

Comment: Have you read and applied the lessons from the book "Javascript: The Good Parts"?  Because if you're now comfortable/competent with javascript then that's the logical next step.  It'd be like doing javascript, but without the crap!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The language that is most similar to JavaScript is JavaScript, by definition.

Learning something new by learning something that is exactly the same as what you already know is an oxymoron. If you want to learn something new, you have to, well learn something new. Something that is as *different* as possible, not as *similar* as possible to what you already know.

That being said, if you want to learn something *about JavaScript*, I suggest you learn some of the languages that influenced its design the most: Scheme (lexical scoping, nested, first-class and higher-order procedures, procedures/closures instead of objects as the unit of encapsulation, a single ubiquitous powerful data structure), NewtonScript (prototype-based OO) and Act1 (differential inheritance) as well as Self (the prototypical prototype-based OO language which inspired both NewtonScript and Act1).

Comment: Similar: having a resemblance in appearance, character, or quantity, without being identical.

Comment: The OP asked for "most similar", i.e. `JavaScript + ε, where ε → 0`. And, when learning, that's really not useful.

Comment: What a pedantic answer.  You fail at NLP.  +1 anyway

Answer (score 5):

Since the other answers cite the languages that inspired Javascript, I'll cite the languages inspired by Javascript. TypeScript and CoffeeScript are very close to Javascript with a few improvements; as jk. pointed out in his comment, there is also ActionScript, which is a bit stricter than Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out [Io](http://iolanguage.org) which is a dynamic prototype-based programming language. The author describes it as conceptually simple, consistent and easily embedded and extended. It's highly dynamic and highly concurrent. The book [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks) has a chapter about it as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_%28programming_language%29) has all those features.

It's actually a major inspiration for JavaScript (some say it's the predecessor).

Unfortunately I don't know how much actual use it gets these days (outside of teaching).